# Can you please explain about Chi Route - Golang in this case

Tags: rest, go

I have learned Golang, Chi Router and I have a question

https://github.com/go-chi/chi/blob/master/_examples/rest/main.go#L83

```
        r.Route("/{articleID}", func(r chi.Router) {
            r.Use(ArticleCtx)            // Load the *Article on the request context
            r.Get("/", GetArticle)       // GET /articles/123
            r.Put("/", UpdateArticle)    // PUT /articles/123
            r.Delete("/", DeleteArticle) // DELETE /articles/123
        })
```

According to document r.Route will return chi.Router
https://pkg.go.dev/github.com/go-chi/chi/v5@v5.0.1#Mux.Route

But in above code, I see that r.Route(...) does not return anything.

Is it OK?

Comment: what does it mean to be "OK"? The code compiles. The return type is ignored, that's all. It returns `Router` in case you want to chain calls

Comment: Hi, I means that in case of the function defines to return the value, but it doesn't, it is still OK or it breaks the code?

Comment: no, it will compile just fine

Answer (score 0):

`Route` (1) creates a new Mux with a fresh middleware stack and (2) mounts it along the pattern as a subrouter.

```
func (mx *Mux) Route(pattern string, fn func(r Router)) Router {
    if fn == nil {
        panic(fmt.Sprintf("chi: attempting to Route() a nil subrouter on '%s'", pattern))
    }
    subRouter := NewRouter()
    fn(subRouter)
    mx.Mount(pattern, subRouter)
    return subRouter
}
```

In your example the value is just discarded and its totally fine. By the way, [InfluxDB uses chi](https://github.com/influxdata/influxdb/blob/master/http/api_handler.go), so you can check a more complex case of usage when documentation is not enough.